# Looking for any information on the painting and artist

Tags: cantonese

Any information helps. it was a thrift store find and it has what i think is a Hong Kong industry and trade sticker on the back. It’s silk in a Michael’s frame.

thank you[image]

Answer (score 1):

The subject of the painting is probably 媽祖, also called 天后. It doesn't look like a good painting and was probably done in a workshop, so I don't think it was painted by somebody recognizable